# Water into our kitchen cabinet due to a leakage from our upstairs neighbor

Tags: cabinets, water-damage

The fridge water pipe in our upstairs neighbor broke and leaked water into our kitchen.

The dishwasher GFCI outlet went out. But hopefully it will be back on when it dries out.

We are more worried about a potential damage to our kitchen cabinet. In particular, there seems to be some delamination (?) on the bottom side of the top wall cabinets.

Is this something serious or will it be okay once it dries out?

[image: cabinet kitchen delamination due to water?]

Comment: Serious enogh to have neighbor insurance pay for the repairs

Comment: Theres no guarantee that they will be fine. They have lost some strength. Its hard to tell from photos. I  would be claiming from mine or the neighbours insurance.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a rental, you need to take pictures and notify the landlord in writing about the leak and possible cabinet damage. If it's your own unit, take pictures and notify the upstairs owners of possible damage. Many cabinets are made with particle board and covered  with a veneer. They do not like water or excessive moisture. Once they get wet, chances are they'll swell up and the damage will be done. They won't shrink back down. So you'll have to monitor carefully and if you see any swelling or veneer becoming unglued, file a claim if it's yours or tell the landlord if it's a rental.